# http://localhost:3001/users/signup 404 (Not Found)

Tags: javascript, mysql, sequelize.js

Hello I've tried to create my route users with sequelize for mysql. But I want to test my request but when I send http://localhost:3001 on my postman I send me http://localhost:3001/users/signup 404 (Not Found). All my users route seems correct I run my nodemon server withou problem and if I run htt://localhost:3001/users I can watch request test

Here is my server.js

```
const http = require("http");
const app = require("./app");

const normalizePort = (val) => {
  const port = parseInt(val, 10);

  if (isNaN(port)) {
    return val;
  }
  if (port >= 0) {
    return port;
  }
  return false;
};
const port = normalizePort(process.env.PORT || "3001");
app.set("port", port);

const errorHandler = (error) => {
  if (error.syscall !== "listen") {
    throw error;
  }
  const address = server.address();
  const bind =
    typeof address === "string" ? "pipe " + address : "port: " + port;
  switch (error.code) {
    case "EACCES":
      console.error(bind + " requires elevated privileges.");
      process.exit(1);
      break;
    case "EADDRINUSE":
      console.error(bind + " is already in use.");
      process.exit(1);
      break;
    default:
      throw error;
  }
};

const server = http.createServer(app);

server.on("error", errorHandler);
server.on("listening", () => {
  const address = server.address();
  const bind = typeof address === "string" ? "pipe " + address : "port " + port;
  console.log("Listening on " + bind);
});

server.listen(port, () =>
  console.log(`Server listening at http://localhost:${port}`)
);
```

my app.js

```html
const express = require("express");
//crééer un application express
const path = require("path");
const models = require("./models");

//variable d'environnement

require("dotenv").config();
console.log(process.env);

const morgan = require("morgan");

//mysql importation connexion

const app = express();

app.use(morgan("dev"));
//import des routes
const authRoutes = require("./routes/user");

//intercepter toute requête d'un contenttype.json
app.use(express.json());

// middlewear general qui s'applique à toute les roots qui permet de gerer les CORS
app.use((req, res, next) => {
  res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
  res.setHeader(
    "Access-Control-Allow-Headers",
    "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content, Accept, Content-Type, Authorization"
  );
  res.setHeader(
    "Access-Control-Allow-Methods",
    "GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, PATCH, OPTIONS"
  );
  next();
});

//Gestion de la ressource images de façon statique
app.use("/images", express.static(path.join(__dirname, "images")));

//routes
app.use("/api/users", authRoutes);

// pour exporter l'application/constante pour acceder aux fichiers depuis notre server node
module.exports = app;
```

my route

```html
const express = require("express");
const router = express.Router();
const userCtrl = require("../controllers/users");

router.post("/signup", userCtrl.signup);
router.post("/login", userCtrl.login);

module.exports = router;
```

And my models

```html
const { Model } = require("sequelize");

module.exports = (Sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  class User extends Model {
    toJSON() {
      return {
        ...this.get(),
      };
    }
  }
  User.init(
    {
      id: { type: DataTypes.UUID, defaultValue: DataTypes.UUIDV4 }, //A universally unique identifier (UUID) , UUIDV4 Random Generation
      nom: { type: DataTypes.STRING, allowNull: false },
      prenom: { type: DataTypes.STRING, allowNull: false },
      email: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING,
        allowNull: false,
        validate: { notNull: true, notEmpty: true, isEmail: true },
      },
      status: { type: DataTypes.STRING, allowNull: false },
      password: { type: DataTypes.STRING, required: true },
    },
    { Sequelize, tableName: "users", modelName: "User" }
  );
  return User;
};
```

And my controllers: users

```html
const bcrypt = require("bcrypt");
const jwt = require("jsonwebtoken");
const User = require("../models/users");

const db = require("../config/db");

//la requête SQL pour envoyer les données dans la table user
exports.signup = (req, res) => {
  bcrypt
    .hash(req.body.password, 10)
    .then((hash) => {
      const user = new User({
        email: req.body.email,
        password: hash,
      });
      db.query("INSERT INTO users SET ?", user, (error, results) => {
        if (error) {
          console.log(error);
          res.json({ error });
        } else {
          console.log("results");
          console.log(results);
          res.json({ message: "utilisateur enregistré" });
        }
      });
    })
    .catch((error) => res.status(500).json({ error }));
};

//la requête SQL pour comparer les données dans la table user
exports.login = (req, res) => {
  const email = req.body.email;
  db.query("SELECT * FROM user WHERE email = ?", email, (error, results) => {
    if (error) {
      console.log(error);
      console.log("error");
      res.json({ error });
    } else {
      console.log("result");
      console.log(results);
      res.json({ message: "email présent dans la base de donnée" });
    }
  });
};

console.log({ email: "pas d'erreur" });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your Users' route is `api/users/`, so you should make your request to `http://localhost:3001/api/users/signup`

Comment: Sorry I write it wrong my  "http://localhost:3001/api/users/login  Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)" and in my postman it send me an error 404

Comment: It's the same issue. In your `app.js` you have this line: `app.use("/api/users", authRoutes);`. So, any route defined in the `users` router is preceded with `api/users`. If you try to use just `users/...` without `api`, express won't be able to find the route.

Comment: Thank you for u answer but I put all with api/users and than I test the route with localhost:3001/api/users/login. I don't see the error on my routes. Did I miss a point without api ?